# How to perfectly loop feTurbulence animation

Tags: animation, svg, svg-animate, svg-filters, smil

I am working with this following and trying `SMIL animation` for the first time.

If you take a look, you would realize that the animation is not smooth, there is a jump at the end.

How can I make this to run smoothly without any jump?

```html
<svg class="layer1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
      <defs>
    <filter id="trip">
        <feTurbulence id="turbulence" baseFrequency="10" numOctaves="20" seed="10" stitchTiles="stitch">
            <animate id="noiseAnimate" attributeName="baseFrequency" attributeType="XML" from="10" to="15" begin="0s" dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
        </feTurbulence>
        <feDisplacementMap in="SourceGraphic" scale="1"></feDisplacementMap>
      </filter>
 
</defs>
<rect class="bg" id="bg" width="200" height="200" fill="black">
</rect>
<rect class="bg" id="bg" x="50" y="50" width="30" height="30" fill="white" filter="url(#trip)">
</rect>
</svg>
```

Comment: Don't animate basefrequency - it looks weird and there's no way to loop it. Instead add a feColorMatrix/hue-rotate from 0 to 360. It will seamlessly loop.  Example https://codepen.io/mullany/pen/AZqQqB?editors=1010

Comment: @MichaelMullany baseFrequency can be animated continuously as long as `stitchTiles="noStitch"` is set. But using `baseFrequency="10"` doesn't make much sense. It just means that you only take into acount every tenth of the [Perlin grid cells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise#Grid_definition) per direction for every pixel drawn. Animating this value to 15 means that at the upper left corner the grid cell does not change at all, while the bottom right corner moves through >3000 cells during one loop.

Comment: That's what I meant by "it looks weird" - the upper left changes less than the rest at all frequency changes. And what I should have said is that it can't be animated "indefinitely" - rather than "continuously" - at some point you have to reverse the animation or you'll get out of the baseFrequency range at which your animation looks right. (Not for this specific animation though - your answer looks just fine with basefrequency and this time range)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's ignore the question whether your animation is a good choice, and just look at the syntax involved.

```
<animate ... from="10" to="15" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
```

The behavior of this animation is just the same as the CSS [property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-direction) `animation-direction: normal`:

> [E]ach time the animation cycles, the animation will reset to the beginning state and start over again.

After moving from 10 to 15, it jumps back to 10 and starts over.

While CSS has a value of `animation-direction: alternate` to describe an animation that moves smoothly forth and back, the same does not exist for SMIL. Instead, you have to describe a movement that has three values: the start value, the end value, and the start value again. This cannot be described with the `from` and `to` attributes, but with [`values`](https://svgwg.org/specs/animations/#ValuesAttribute).

Additionally, you have to set the [`keyTimes`](https://svgwg.org/specs/animations/#KeyTimesAttribute) attribute. In an interval of 0...1 it describes when, relative to the simple duration, the value is reached.

```
<animate ... values="10;15;10" keyTimes="0;.5;1" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
```

*Note: For animating `baseFrequency`, you have to set `stitchTiles="noStitch"`, as otherwise the frequency is changed in such discrete steps that the [Perlin cell size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise#Grid_definition) is always an integral fraction of the primitive filter region size.*

```html
<svg class="layer1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
      <defs>
    <filter id="trip">
        <feTurbulence id="turbulence" baseFrequency="10" numOctaves="20"
                      seed="10" stitchTiles="noStitch">
            <animate id="noiseAnimate" attributeName="baseFrequency" attributeType="XML"
                     values="10;15;10" keyTimes="0;.5;1" begin="0s" dur="5s"
                     repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
        </feTurbulence>
        <feDisplacementMap in="SourceGraphic" scale="1"></feDisplacementMap>
      </filter>
 
</defs>
<rect class="bg" id="bg" width="200" height="200" fill="black">
</rect>
<rect class="bg" id="bg" x="50" y="50" width="30" height="30" fill="white" filter="url(#trip)">
</rect>
</svg>
```

Comment: many thanks for this and the detailed explanation. I did not work as much with SMIL as I did with CSS animation. But I understood SMIL is extremely powerful too. However, there is not a lot of material available that breaks down SMIL animation in detail. If such material exists and you can point me to the direction would be great.

Comment: While on the topic, I want to understand a few things here. Do I understand that one must provide the same number of  values in `<animate>values</animate>` and `<animate>keyTimes</animate>` . For example, if I put 10 values in  `<animate>values</animate>` , I must provide 10 values in `<animate>keyTimes</animate>` too. Do I also understand that `<animate>keyTimes</animate>` values are equivalent to CSS `@keyframes animName 10%,   20%, 30%` and `<animate>values</animate>` equivalent to  `@keyframes animName 10%,{opacity:0.1}   20%{opacity:0.2}, 30%{opacity:0.3}`.

Comment: SVG filters are bomb !!! and it seems SMIL is the only way to animate them. Therefore, I want to be fluent in SMIL as much as I am in CSS animation.

Comment: The source for SMIL animation information is the [spec](https://svgwg.org/specs/animations/), obviously. Don't mind all the red color, the text is mostly a verbatim copy of the SVG 1.1 [chapter on animations](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/animate.html), and the existing browser implementations are remarkably consistent and complete. Your understanding of keyTimes/values is correct, see [Attributes that define animation values over time](https://svgwg.org/specs/animations/#ValueAttributes) for a detailed discussion.

Comment: @ ccprog a follow up Q to this. Can you please confirm, should I desire the time to be equally spaced out between (spends exactly same time on each values) `values`, can I provide `calcMode=discrete`, instead of providing any `keyTimes` values, so that timing can be worked out by svg internal mechanism by itself, instead of me trying to figuring out all equally spaced values for all `values` between `0 and 1`?

Comment: You found one of the rare cases where the regular cross-references to the SMIL specification are actually needed. [Quote:](https://www.w3.org/TR/smil-animation/#AnimFuncCalcMode) If `calcMode` is set to "discrete", "linear" or "spline", but the `keyTimes` attribute is not specified, the values in the values attribute are assumed to be equally spaced through the animation duration...For _discrete_, the duration is divided into equal time periods, one per value...For _linear_ and _spline_, the duration is divided into n-1 even periods [of] linear interpolation between the values...

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation and your time.